# Software selection screen in Ubuntu installer

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments, system-installation, software-installation, ubuntu-minimal

While installing Ubuntu 12.04, I am asked to choose whether to install these predefined collections of software, which are displayed in this screen:

[image]

I am just interested in having a standard Ubuntu 12.04 desktop (possibly running Unity). I do not have disk space issues, so it wouldn't be a problem to install something I don't need if it will simplify the installation.

Could you suggest me what software I should select?

I already tried this installation before. After the completion of the installation, I am only shown a terminal, but not the login GUI. In case I am shown the terminal again, could you suggest what commands I should run?

**EDIT:**

List of software options:

- ...
- Basic Ubuntu server
- openSSH server
- ...
- Openstack
- ...
- Edubuntu desktop
- Kubuntu desktop
- Kubuntu full
- LadSPA/LV2/DSSI audio plugins
- large selection of font packages
- Lubuntu minimal installation
- Mythbuntu additional roles
- Mythbuntu frontend
- Mythbuntu master backend
- Mythbuntu slave backend
- Tone generation and editing suite
- Ubuntu LXDE desktop
- Ubuntu desktop
- Ubuntu dektio USB
- Video creation and editing suite
- Xubuntu desktop
- Manual package selection

Comment: Why you choose this image ? Is this a server image ? Download [Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) image instead of server and you will not bother what packages to install. Ubuntu desktop comes with a desktop environment by default.

Comment: I have to use this image because I'm working on a university lab computer that only allows this type of installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose Kubuntu desktop or Ubuntu desktop package from the software list and then press continue.

You will be presented with a GUI login screen.

Comment: Thanks, will it then install Unity desktop?

Comment: is there any ubuntu desktop package in that list?

Comment: Ubuntu desktop = Unity desktop.

Comment: Thanks, I added the list of available choices that do not appear in the image.

Comment: yes there was Ubuntu desktop on that list.Go and install it.